# Duplicated CoreData reference in a relationship using MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

My problem has been a pain for quite a while. What's happening is that I'm using MagicalRecord to manage my CoreData db, and I'm having an issue with a certain model relationship.

I have a many-to-many relationship between Contact and Tag. When I add a Tag to a Contact, everything is fine and the Tag object shows as:

```
<DMTag: 0x7b0414b0> (entity: DMTag; id: 0x7d95bb20 <x-coredata://B5BE8668-52A9-49C2-A3AA-7684683C5F2C/DMTag/p70> ; data: {
    contacts =     (
        "0x7d82e6f0 <x-coredata:///DMContact/tB751E1B7-A6D4-4E08-9501-85E5C4A7CF722>"
    );
    identifier = "-68";
    name = Andreas;
    removed = 0;
    synchronized = 0;
}
```

But when I save the context, here's what happen next (this is a print inside the callback, right after the save context):

```
<DMTag: 0x7b0414b0> (entity: DMTag; id: 0x7d95bb20 <x-coredata://B5BE8668-52A9-49C2-A3AA-7684683C5F2C/DMTag/p70> ; data: {
    contacts =     (
        "0x7b237f00 <x-coredata://B5BE8668-52A9-49C2-A3AA-7684683C5F2C/DMContact/p344>",
        "0x7b237f00 <x-coredata://B5BE8668-52A9-49C2-A3AA-7684683C5F2C/DMContact/p344>"
    );
    identifier = "-68";
    name = Andreas;
    removed = 0;
    synchronized = 0;
}
```

This duplicate is coming from nowhere, in my point of view. The save context I mentioned is as:

```
[self.context saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
```

and self.context is declared as

```
self.context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
```

Any ideas if I'm making any beginner's mistake or maybe using MagicalRecord or Core Data in a wrong way?

Thanks in advance.